# What's the difference between running python script in interactive shell and in Terminal of Linux(ubuntu 13)?

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal, interpreter

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, char):
            self.char = char
            self.position = 'f'

    def setMove(self):
            while True:
                    print(self.char + ' make a move')
                    self.position = input()
                    if self.position.isdigit():
                            break
    def getMove(self):
            return int(self.position)

    def makeMove(self):
            self.setMove()
            board[self.getMove()].fillCell(self)



class Cell():
    def __init__(self):
            self.filled = False
            self.image = '_'

    def __str__(self):
            return self.image

    def fillCell(self, player):
            if not self.filled:
                    self.image = player.char
                    self.filled = True
            else:
                    player.makeMove()


class Board(list):
    def __init__(self,cells):
            super(list,self).__init__(cells)

    def __str__(self):
            return '\n'.join([chunk for chunk in self._chunks()])

    def _chunks(self):
            chunk_len = 3

            for i in range(0,len(self),chunk_len):
                    yield ' '.join([cell.image for cell in self[i:i+3]])


    def checkRow(self,player):
        chunk_len = 3
        test_list = [player.char for i in range(chunk_len)]

        for idx in range(0,len(self)-1,chunk_len):
            return ([cell.image for cell in self[idx:idx    +chunk_len]] ==    test_list)






board = Board([Cell() for i in range(9)])

if __name__ == '__main__':



pl1 = Player('x')
pl2 = Player('o')



while True:
    print(board)      

    pl1.makeMove()


    print(board)

    pl2.makeMove()
```

This is my script. When i ran it in python shell, it counld totally work out. However when i tried to do the same thing in Terminal, i just got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tictactoe.py", line 63, in <module>
board = Board([Cell() for i in range(9)])
File "tictactoe.py", line 39, in __init__
super().__init__(cells)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

then i google it,i add the argument.I ran this script again, it showed a different error.

```
x make a move

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tictactoe.py", line 77, in <module>
pl1.makeMove()
File "tictactoe.py", line 16, in makeMove
self.setMove()
File "tictactoe.py", line 10, in setMove
if self.position.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

it didn't surprise me when error occurred, what really surprised me the "board" didn't show  up. So if can help that would do me great help.

Comment: Looks like you're running a Python 3 script in Python 2. `super()` and `input()` work differently there.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between running a python script in an interactive shell and in Terminal of Linux is that you can have multiple verions of Python installed.  If the wrong one runs, you need to figure out what happened.

If you run a Python script in an interactive shell, it also uses the libraries corresponding to the Python binary that it gets run in.

Comment: so how can i change the version of python running in my terminal.